# Is it possible to play Netflix Watch Instantly on a PS3 Slim without the DVD?

Tags: ps3, netflix

I was shipped a Netflix DVD but lost it. Is there any way to stream Netflix "Watch Instantly" without the DVD?

Comment: need more details, like what device and such...don't assume that you can use the title and the description together... replicate what is in the title into the description and everything will be clearer... *Welcome to SuperUser!*

Comment: Please see the FAQ, questions about video game consoles are explicitly called out as off-topic on Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, but I hear the feature is planned for an upcoming firmware update.

Comment: Any idea when that might be? Weeks or months from now?